# Can't update single field in dynamodb using boto3

Tags: python, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, localstack

When I'm trying to update a single field in my dynamodb table with `update_item` method, for some reason it's updating the whole row.

[before updating the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pooxY.png)

[after updating the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEU8z.png)

My updating method:

```
    def operate_likes(self, statistic: dict):
        statistic_id = statistic.get('page_id')
        table = self.__db.Table('Statistic')
        response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                'page_id': statistic_id
            },
            UpdateExpression="SET liked_posts_amount = :lpa",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':lpa': statistic.get('liked_posts_amount')
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

My dynamodb scheme:

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "page_id",
      "AttributeType": "N"
    }
  ],
  "TableName": "Statistic",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "page_id",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "CreationDateTime": "2022-07-11T11:04:57.318Z",
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 3,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 3
  },
  "TableSizeBytes": 63,
  "ItemCount": 2,
  "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/Statistic"
}
```

I was searching the reason causing it but my attempts weren't successful. Any ideas why might this be happening? Feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: You haven't explained what is the issue. What do you expect after the update? How is it different from current outcome?

Comment: @Marcin I'm trying to update single attribute `liked_posts_amount` but instead all other attributes are getting washed out
(See hyperlinked screenshots at the beginning of the post)